# How do I manage the ParseFiles that my Parse account has created?

Tags: parse-platform

My application creates a ParseFile and saves it in the background.

Since the ParseFiles don't show up in the web-based Data Browser for my Parse account, is there anyway for me to get a list of the ParseFiles created for my account or to manage them in anyway (e.g. delete,view,etc)?

Comment: Are you asking in a general sense? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried searching Parse documentation on managing parse files and couldn't find any. And since they don't show up in the Data browser, you can't even get a list of what ParseFiles you've created.

Comment: There is nothing like a file manager. When you create a file, you need to associate it to an object. Then you can see it in the data browser. Otherwise, there is no way. Also in the settings, there should be an option to delete unused files.